# Python while Loop output to List

Tags: python, list, while-loop

I wrote a simple code that takes as input a .wav file and then finds the frequencies and returns the corresponding note. However, in order to add some more functionality, I need the output to be a list.
A simplified pseudo code of what I have looks like this:

```
while some condition = true:
    compute various things
    print(frequency)
```

It does print my frequencies correctly, however since it's in a while loop and for every note found it outputs the frequency, the output looks like this:

```
A2
G3
B4
A2
...
```

When I use list append, it returns me this:

```
["A2"]
["G3"]
["B4"]
["A2"]
...
```

Whereas I need something like this:

```
["A2", "G3", "B4", "A2", ...]
```

I really don't know how to go about this and to get my output as a list.

Comment: Can you post your code

Comment: you need to show how you're appending, since that is the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating an empty list before the while loop, then appending to it within the loop:

```
result_list = []
while some condition = true:
    compute various things
    result_list.append(frequency)
    print(frequency)
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks.
I swear I tried if before, been sitting in front of this code the whole day, probably just needed a break. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to print the list outside the while block?

```
result_list = []
while some condition = true:
    compute various things
    result_list.append(frequency)
print(frequency)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put the print statement outside the while:

```
result_list = []
while some condition = true:
    compute various things
    result_list.append(frequency)
print(frequency)
```