# How to turn this while loop into a for loop and output a list with float values?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, while-loop

I am working on this Python code for my thesis. Let's say

```
x1 = 0.1
x2 = 0.5
y1 = 0.1
y2 = 0.99
d = 0.1

def Calculate():
  tan_theta = ((y2-y1)/(x2-x1))
  theta = math.atan(tan_theta)

  i = x1  
  while (i < x2):
    print(i)
    i = i + d * math.cos(theta)

  j = y1
    while (j < y2):
      print(j)
      j = j + d * math.sin(theta)

Calculate()
```

The values outputted are correct as:

```
0.1
0.140993850103
...

0.1
0.191211316479
...
```

But I need them to be on a list such as:

```
[0.1  0.140993850103  ...]
[0.1  0.191211316479  ...]
```

I also needed the output to become a list and did some examples previously done such as [Python while Loop output to List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67403096/python-while-loop-output-to-list) but it did not work for me.

```
  result_list = []
  i = x1  
  while (i < x2):
    i = i + d * math.cos(theta)
    result_list.append(i)
    print(i)

result_list2 = []
  j = y1
    while (j < y2):
      j = j + d * math.sin(theta)
      result_list2.append(j)
      print(j)
```

It was still outputting the same results as before and it even outputted values outside the range.

I also tried using a For Loop by using numpy since I am dealing with float values. I tried using:

```
import numpy as np

  for i in [np.arange(x1, x2, x1 + d * math.cos(theta))]:
    print(i)

  for j in [np.arange(y1, y2, y1 + d * math.sin(theta))]:
    print(j)
```

But the values I get are:

```
[0.1  0.24099385 0.3819877]
[0.1  0.29121132  0.48242263  0.67363395  0.86484527]
```

which are wrong.
I should also be getting the same amount of values (i.e. 3 'x' values and 3 'y' values and not 3 'x' and 5 'y'.

I'm not sure how to progress now as I have done everything I can think of.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are two questions here, which makes it not appropriate for our format (you are only supposed to ask one at a time). The questions I see are: 1) how to convert the `while` loop to a `for` loop? 2) how to make a list out of values that are computed each time through a loop?

Comment: For the first question, I will instead ask you the questions, because I think you can figure it out yourself. Can you think of a way to use math ahead of time to figure out how many times the loop should run? If you have a value that tells you how many times the loop ran before (so e.g. it's `0` the first time through, `1` the second etc.), can you think of a way to use math with that value to determine the required value for `i`? Given those pieces, do you see how to proceed?

Comment: For the second question, I really can only refer you back to the link that you found yourself. Telling us "it did not work for me" is not helpful. The only thing you appear to have changed in the next code example (I **assume** you mean "this is the code I tried, after reading those other examples"; but you should *say that explicitly*) is to create `list1 = []`, but then do nothing with it. Please *read the other code more carefully*. Notice how the other examples have a line with the word `append` in it? Notice how your code does not?

Comment: "...which are wrong." I can't reproduce this; if I use the same value of `d` and `theta` for the `np.arange` call, then it produce the same values as the manual loop. As for the number of values you get, that simply depends on how many values fit within the specified endpoints. You  definitely don't need Numpy for this task - yet - and you should *make sure you properly understand the language fundamentals* before trying to use it.

Comment: While I have your attention, please read the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you post your code *exactly* as you actually have it, and only post actual code that you have actually tried running (i.e., copy and paste things, don't rely on your memory). For example, I know that your actual code doesn't actually say `Import numpy as np`, with a capital `I`, because Python is case-sensitive and that would cause a syntax error. The indentation shown in some of your code is also not valid.

Comment: Hi @Karl, thank you for your input. I have made some edits to correct some of the code. For the first question, I will think of something and try that. For the second question, I have indeed written the wrong code and have amended it but the output that I have written were outputted from the code similar to the example. I only used Numpy because it was the only way I can use float values for the For Loop.

Comment: "It was still outputting the same results as before and it even outputted values outside the range." I don't think I understand what you mean by this. Of course it still prints the individual values as they are calculated, because you still have a `print` call inside the loop, with that exact purpose. You should *also* find that the list `result_list` accumulates values; you should try displaying that list in order to see the result. If you are saying that this somehow changes the individual numbers that are calculated, I cannot reproduce that behaviour.

Comment: I think right now, if you really can't make any progress on your own, instead focus on trying to make a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem. We should be able to copy and paste your code block and see it do the wrong thing, exactly in the way you describe, along with an understanding of what the right thing is instead.

Comment: Okay I will do that and ask another question with minimal, reproducible example of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most **Pythonic** way to reach what you are looking for is just to create your own `float_range` to emulate the `range`, for example:

```py
import math

x1 = 0.1
x2 = 0.5
y1 = 0.1
y2 = 0.99
d = 0.1


def float_range(beg, end, increment):
    while beg < end:
        yield beg
        beg += increment


def Calculate():
    tan_theta = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)
    theta = math.atan(tan_theta)

    list_x = list(float_range(x1, x2, d * math.cos(theta)))
    print(list_x)

    list_y = list(float_range(y1, y2, d * math.sin(theta)))
    print(list_y)


Calculate()
```

Also, you can use it in a for loop, like:

```py
for x in float_range(y1, y2, d * math.sin(theta)):
    print(x)
```