# How to output a list using a while loop?

Tags: python, list, while-loop

Firstly, I have tried doing this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67403096/python-while-loop-output-to-list) but have no success in outputting a list using a while loop.

I have done the suggestions of both @
Someone_who_likes_SE and @ace1234

The code I have is this:

```
import math

x1 = 0.1
x2 = 0.5
d = 0.2
theta = 1.14840969035

x_list = []
i = x1
while (i < x2):
  i = i + d * math.cos(theta)
  x_list.append(i)

print(x_list)
```

The output are:

```
[0.181987700205 0.263975400411 0.345963100616 0.427950800822 0.5099385010273055]
```

Is there a way to get the 0.1 at the start?
The 0.50999385010273055 should also not be there as it is over 0.5.

Comment: It's being appended to the list, only you have `print(i)` which is causing this behavior.

Comment: You could print the list after the for loop to get expected answer.

Comment: "Is there a way to get the 0.1 at the start?" Yes; change the code such that it actually gets put into the list. "The 0.50999385010273055 should also not be there as it is over 0.5." Think carefully about the order of the steps in your code. When `i < x2` is checked, is that before or after adding the step to `i`? When `x_list.append(i)` happens, is that before or after? Do you see why that causes a problem?

Comment: Please do not repeatedly edit your post to reflect "I tried something from this answer and now I have a *different* problem". That leaves the answers out of sync, and confuses anyone who comes by afterwards. Please remember that Stack Overflow is **not a discussion forum**. If you have an issue with an answer, you should use the comments on that answer to get clarification, or if appropriate, start over and ask a new question.

Comment: Better ask a new question, instead of editing the same question.

Answer (score 2):

Change the `while` loop to -

```
while (i < x2):
  i = i + d * math.cos(theta)
  x_list.append(i)

print(x_list)
```

You want the list, so you should print the list. But what you have done is print `i`

Edit - If you want `0.1` in start and want to remove `0.50....` then move `append` method up like this -

```
while (i < x2):
  x_list.append(i)
  i = i + d * math.cos(theta)

print(x_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's actually working.

Line 11 is actually appending to the list:

```
import math

x1 = 0.1
x2 = 0.5
d = 0.2
theta = 1.14840969035

x_list = []
i = x1
while (i < x2):
  print(i)
  i = i + d * math.cos(theta)
  x_list.append(i) # <--- appending
```

only you're not printing it out.

```
import math

x1 = 0.1
x2 = 0.5
d = 0.2
theta = 1.14840969035

x_list = []
i = x1
while (i < x2):
  print(i) # <--- prints out the numbers.
  i = i + d * math.cos(theta)
  x_list.append(i)
```

So this will work:

```
import math

x1 = 0.1
x2 = 0.5
d = 0.2
theta = 1.14840969035

x_list = []
i = x1
while (i < x2):
  #print(i)
  i = i + d * math.cos(theta)
  x_list.append(i)

print(x_list)
```

Output:

```
[0.18198770020501776, 0.26397540041003553, 0.3459631006150533, 0.4279508008200711, 0.5099385010250889]
```

Answer (score 1):

The output that you saw is the print that I commented below. If you print the list object after loop the result is that you're expecting.

```
import math

x1 = 0.1
x2 = 0.5
d = 0.2
theta = 1.14840969035

x_list = []
i = x1
while (i < x2):
  #print(i) <--- this is that you was seing!
  i = i + d * math.cos(theta)
  x_list.append(i)

## try print the list object:
print(x_list)
```